# JavaScript: Click event that accept a parameter named e

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans-8

I need help. I have to write a javascript and jQuery code, so when I click on one of the caption link (Ex: Big Horns, Lower Kings) it show get the image and title for that link and display it.

First: I have to create an event handler for the read event method, which I did.

Second: I have to use the each method to run a function for each **A** element. And also add jQuery code that gets the URL and caption for each image and preloads the image it. I don't think if I did the preloading right or not.

**Third: I have to add an event handler for the click event of each link.The function for this event handler should accept a parameter named event. The jQuery code for this event handler should display the image and caption for the link that was clicked. In addition, it should use the evt parameter to cancel the default action of the link.
I am stuck on the third problem: Any help, please.**

Here is my HTML, Javascript, and CSS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
var url, title;
$("a").each(function() {
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    title = $(this).attr("title");
    
    $("a").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("#caption").text(title);
        $("img").attr('src', url);
    });
    
});
});
```

```css
article, aside, figure, footer, header, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1, h2, ul, p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
h1 {
 padding-bottom: .25em;
 color: blue;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: .5em 0;
}
li {
 padding: 0 0.25em;
 display: inline;
}
#caption, #gallery {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="image_gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section>
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <ul id="image_list">
        <li><a href="images/casting1.jpg" title="Casting on the Upper Kings">Upper Kings</a></li>
        <li><a href="images/casting2.jpg" title="Casting on the Lower Kings">Lower Kings</a></li>
        <li><a href="images/catchrelease.jpg" title="Catch and Release on the Big Horn">Big Horn</a></li>
        <li><a href="images/fish.jpg" title="Catching on the South Fork">South Fork</a></li>
        <li><a href="images/lures.jpg" title="The Lures for Catching">Lures</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="caption">Casting on the Upper Kings</h2>
    <p id="gallery">
     <img src="images/casting1.jpg" alt="Image Gallery area" id="image">
    </p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmonnLf7/).

The JavaScript code you want looks like this

```
$('a').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); // cancel default action of link

  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  var title = $(this).attr("title");

  $('#caption').text(title);
  $('img').attr('src', url); // change the image tag's source attribute to our url variable

});
```

I used pictures of castles because, well, your captions reminded me of castles.

Comment: OP gets A+ on his assignment. Easy.

Comment: Hey, I just update my code. The first time when I run the code and click on any of the link, it will go to the last image with the title, and be one that one image with the title. Can you you tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Take a look at the Fiddle. The `$('a').click()` event code must be outside of the `$(document).ready()` code. Otherwise you will get the issue you are having.

Comment: When I put the $('a').click() field out the $(document).read() code, it didn't work for me. I had to change the $('a').click() to $(document).on('click', 'a', function(), and it work. Thanks to everyone for the help!